# Finding the vertical and horizontal tangents to the polar curve $r=\theta$?

Tags: polar-coordinates, tangent-line

So there's this curve in polar coordinates

$r=\theta$ for $0\le\theta\le2\pi$

and I need to find the $\theta$ values for all of its vertical and horizontal tangents.
so I've got

$x=rcos\theta=\theta cos\theta$ and

$y=\theta sin\theta$,

which gives

$\displaystyle\frac{dx}{d\theta}=cos\theta-\theta sin\theta$ and

$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{d\theta}=sin\theta+\theta cos\theta$.

So the slope should be 
$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\displaystyle\frac{sin\theta+\theta cos\theta}{cos\theta-\theta sin\theta}$.

So for the tangent to be horizontal, I need ${sin\theta+\theta cos\theta}=0$, but I can't see how to solve this, except just by seeing that it works when $\theta=0.$ As for the vertical tangent, I'm not sure how to find $\theta$ so that $cos\theta-\theta sin\theta=0$.

Comment: Other solutions are $\theta \approx 2.02875783811043,4.91318043943488$ as found by Wolfram alpha.

Comment: Which tangent (vertical/horizontal) are these solutions for? Can you please provide me this link?

Comment: These are for $dy/dz = 0$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BSin%5Bx%5D%2BxCos%5Bx%5D%3D%3D0,+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+2Pi%5D